# How to participate in the Early Access for Linux systems?

Tags: arma-3

I've read that ARMA 3 has now [Early Access option for Linux systems](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Arma_3). As I'm keen on playing this simulation FPS, I would like to know how to get access to it.

On the Steam stores I only can see the Windows logo for supported systems. Now I don't want to buy it just to get disappointed or find out that this wouldn't be the right way.

**How can I get Early Access to ARMA 3 for Linux systems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://dev.arma3.com/ports) is the official 'Experimental Port' page. It explains that you should go to the [Steam page for the game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/107410/), purchase it, and it will automatically download the data for Mac or Linux, depending on the platform you are installing from.